# CSRF token verification error on Samsung s7

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, laravel, csrf

All devices with the ajax request working, but only Samsung s7, keep on getting 419 error on ajax request.

I have csrf meta

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

On ajax request attached the token

```
$.ajax({
     headers: {
      'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
     },
     url: "{{ route('artwork.save') }}",
     dataType: "json",
     data: {},
     type: 'POST',
     success: function (response) {
        // do something
     },
     error: function (err) {
        // handle error
     }
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to clear both front end and back end cache, then test again.